How to migrate a Spring WebMVC 5 with JSP pages to Spring WebMVC 6?
I have a Spring WebMVC5 application including JSP pages with Apache Tiles rendering. Now WebMVC5 has security issues so we need to upgrade to Spring WebMVC6. Unfortunately Spring WebMVC6 does not support Tiles.
Is there a good practice to migrate in this case?
Thanks.
Tried to migrate WebMVC5 to WebMVC6
